# Has the exponentiation of ordinals a nice geometric model?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinal-numbers

It is well known that the sum $\alpha+\beta$ of two ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ can be defined "geometrically" as the order type of the sum $(\{0\}\times \alpha)\cup(\{1\}\times\beta)$ endowed with the lexicographic order.

Also the product $\alpha\cdot\beta$ of ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ is the order type of the Cartesian product $\beta\times\alpha$ endowed with the lexicographic order.

> What about the exponentiation of ordinals?
>
> Does $\alpha^\beta$ have some nice "geometric'' or combinatorial model?
>
> Maybe as some set of (partial) functions endowed with a suitable well-order?

Comment: "Maybe as some set of (partial) functions endowed with a suitable well-order?" Does "the set of partial functions $\beta\rightarrow\alpha$ which are nonzero at only finitely many values, ordered by comparing the point of least difference" constitute such a characterization? (See [Rosenstein](https://books.google.com/books?id=y3YpdW-sbFsC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=linear+order+exponentiation&source=bl&ots=eSIBSAQXDQ&sig=ACfU3U2HK4B4tjBMVyn_McrGCo5lU-kaRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO1YTC7oHpAhUIH80KHa8WBtAQ6AEwFnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=linear%20order%20exponentiation&f=false).) D

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It is not exactly what you asked for, but I'll mention that some visualization of $\omega^\omega$ can be found here: [Visualizations of ordinal numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599022) and [Intuition for $\omega^\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/336373).

Comment: Adding to the suggestions of @Martin, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278992/how-to-think-about-ordinal-exponentiation might be helpful as well.

Comment: Related: martini's answer to [Ordinal Exponentiation and transfinite induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149187/13130) *AND* [How do you define ordinal exponentiation without induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3037759/13130) (the comments might be of interest).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ordinal exponentiation is a special case of *linear order* exponentiation. For any linear order $L$, element $a\in L$, and ordinal $\beta$ we can define the **$\beta$th power of $L$ at $a$**, which I'll call "$L_a^\beta$," as the set of functions $f:\beta\rightarrow L$ such that all but finitely many $\alpha\in\beta$ have $f(\alpha)=a$. The ordering on this set is given by looking at the last point of difference: $$f\trianglelefteq g\iff f=g\mbox{ or } f(\max\{x:f(x)\not=g(x)\})<g(\max\{x:f(x)\not=g(x)\}).$$

For ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ we have $\alpha^\beta=\alpha_0^\beta$. [Rosenstein's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=y3YpdW-sbFsC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=linear+order+exponentiation&source=bl&ots=eSIBSAQXDQ&sig=ACfU3U2HK4B4tjBMVyn_McrGCo5lU-kaRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO1YTC7oHpAhUIH80KHa8WBtAQ6AEwFnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=linear%20order%20exponentiation&f=false) treats this in some detail (and is generally an awesome book all-around - it's a huge tragedy that it's so hard to find).

What I like about this definition is that it very nicely complements the definition of cardinal exponentiation: they start with the same basic idea of counting functions between sets, but ordinal exponentiation is the "finite support" version.

Comment: It's not well-ordered.  $(1,0,0,...) > (0,1,0,...) > ... > (0,...,0,1,0,...) > ...$.  Maybe replace min with max?

Comment: @MonroeEskew It would make sense to use $\max$ instead if you want to generalize ordinal exponentiation, but it won't be well-ordered if $L$ isn't anyways.

Comment: @nombre That’s ok... I’m just saying that the above definition doesn’t define $\alpha^\beta$ properly.  One needs to use max, by my example.  (Isn’t it right? The definition given is the same as the lex order, which corresponds to the rationals for $\alpha=2, \beta=\omega$.)  But it is easy to show by induction that max works.

Comment: If one thinks of $\omega^\omega$ as the ordertype of the semiring of polynomials $\mathbb N[X]$, then one has to look to the *largest* degree where two polynomials have different coefficients to see which one dominates, not the smallest.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Derp, fixed - thanks!

Comment: Do you need $\beta$ to be well-ordered? It looks to me like this definition still makes sense when $\beta$ is any linear order, so you've really defined a way of exponentiating with two linear orders . . . right?